# How can i remove duplicate files that contain 2 matching strings but keep the rest?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a problem that i can not think how to solve.
I have a directory that contains 1000's of files which each contain a URL with a URL parameter:

File 1:

```
example.com/car/?wheel=tyre
```

File 2:

```
example.com/car/?wheel=rim
```

File 3:

```
test.com/food/?fruit=apple
```

File 4:

```
test.com/food/?fruit=banana
```

File 5:

```
test.co.uk/car/interior=chair
```

File 6:

```
example.co.uk/car/interior=chair
```

I want to remove  duplicate files that contain the same domain name and parameter but keep the first. The item inside the parameter eg. tyre, rim, apple, bananna and chair should be ignored.
so the desired output is below:

File 1:

```
example.com/car/?wheel=tyre
```

File 3:

```
test.com/food/?fruit=apple
```

File 5:

```
test.co.uk/car/interior=chair
```

File 6:

```
example.co.uk/car/interior=chair
```

File 2 has been removed because it is the same domain name and URL parameter name as File 1.
File 4 has been removed because it is the same domain name and URL parameter name as File 3.
File 5 and 6 are kept, because they use different domains even though they use the same URL parameter.

I am thinking i need to first iterate through all files in the directory:

```
FILES=data/urls/*
for i in $FILES
do
  cat $i | *Check for matching domain, then matching parameter*
else
 rm $i
fi
done
```

or maybe search for a  domain name using a for loop, then a nested for loop to check the parameter using uniq.
However i am not sure how to do this.

Any ideas how i can do this?

**EDIT:**
I have added all url's to one file to make them easier to work with using:

```
sed -i -e '$a\' *.txt
cat * > all.txt
```

**Edit 2:**
Some URL's contain multiple folders in the path eg.

```
www.example.com/1/2/3/4/5/?l=123
www.example.com/1/2/3/?1=AAA
```

Comment: This is not a very efficient way to store such things. Nor is it easy to work with them. I'd rather keep them in a database.

Comment: @Tomasz I agree, however i have to deal with the data as it is, i may pipe all files into 1 file to make it easier.

Comment: Files 5 and 6 miss `?` that introduces the parameter. Just for the record.

Comment: Yeah that makes it more difficult because they all have a different pattern

Comment: If the files have different content then they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little Bash script like this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A a                             # declare associative array 
for i in *; do                           # loop through files in directory

  read -r url < "$i"                     # read the url from the file
  domain=${url%%/*}                      # delete longest match from back
  param=${url##*/}                       # delete longest match from start
  param=${param%%=*}                     # delete "=value" from param
  k=$domain$param                        # construct key

  if [[ -n $k && -z ${a[$k]} ]]; then    # check its prior use as key k
    a[$k]=1                              # new key: mark it as such
  else                                   # known/faulty key: delete the file
    echo Delete "$i"                     # Replace with: rm "$i" if satisfied
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is giving me the following error:     ./test.sh: line 6: a: bad array subscript
./test.sh: line 7: a[$k]: bad array subscript

Comment: @jonnyb Can you insert an "echo $k" above the if-statement (below the k-assignment) to see what the bad key is? I don't have a bad key for the files you showed in your post.

Comment: Its not giving me the output of echo $k for some reason, its just giving me the same output as before

Comment: actually , its showing a new empty line in the output so maybe its a space?

Comment: @jonnyb Maybe it does. Maybe you have an empty file. Can you insert an "echo "$i" before the k-assignment? And then check to see if that file actually matches your data specification...

Comment: @jonnyb I edited the script a bit to catch empty keys. Can you check if this solves the error message? The current script action is to delete files that result in empty keys; this is obviously acceptable only in case an empty key really indicates a faulty file.

Comment: The script worked, i had a stray file with empty lines!, i exeuted it in a test environment and it deleted 90% of duplicates however some remain such as: www.example.com/test/test/1/?l=french
www.example.com/test/test/9/?l=bulgarian
www.example.com/test/test/17/?l=brazilian

and

www.test.com/international/schedule/1/0/?l=thai
www.test.com/international/schedule/4/0/?l=thai
www.test.com/international/schedule/5/0/?l=thai
www.test.com/international/schedule/7/0/?l=thai
www.test.com/international/schedule/6/0/?l=thai

Comment: any ideas why they didn't get removed?

Comment: @jonnyb What is the exact content of two respective files that should have been deleted, but that remain after running the script?

Comment: the files contain the url's posted above, i think it may be because some of the urls have a different number of folders: ../../../ so it is messing up the regex?

Comment: @jonnyb Well, not messing up. The script is doing what I think it should, and what I thought is what you wanted : ) Perhaps you can clarify your definition of what constitutes a duplicate in your post/question above by explicitly stating that folder names after the domain are to be disregarded. Then I'll adapt the script accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is it possible for this script to operate without knowing the number of folders? or if it would be easier, modify the script to run and work with 2 folders, 3 folders, 4 folders etc. then i could run all scripts?

Comment: so theire would be 5 versions of the script 1: ../, 2: ../../ 3: ../../../ 4.: ../../../../ 5: ../../../../../

Comment: @jonnyb And I updated the script...

Comment: Thanks very much you have saved me many many hours of manual work!, do you use https://ko-fi.com? i owe you a cofee!

Comment: @jonnyb I'm glad the script worked for you! I didn't know "ko-fi.com" - interesting site; but here, I'm afraid, we do everything for just points, the learning experience and some fun. Thanks for the appreciation though.

Answer (score 1):

With all lines in one file, you can use this Perl code:

```
perl -nle '($d,$p)=m{^(\S+?)/\S+/\??(\w+)=}; $a{"$d$p"}=$_ if "$d$p";
END {print $a{$_} for (keys %a)}' input
```

`input` is the data file, but you can pipe into this Perl command instead. The working is simple. Regex is first used to isolate the domain and **the first** param of each entry. Then the whole line is written to a dictionary, where the earlier isolated parts are the key. Any earlier value is overwritten. In the end the hash is printed.

It produces this output:

```
test.co.uk/car/interior=chair
www.example.com/1/1/?l=spanish
example.com/car/?wheel=rim
www.example.com/1/1/?selectedTab=live&selectedStream=1
example.co.uk/car/interior=chair
test.com/food/?fruit=banana
```

From this input:

```
example.com/car/?wheel=tyre
example.com/car/?wheel=rim
test.com/food/?fruit=apple
test.com/food/?fruit=banana
test.co.uk/car/interior=chair
example.co.uk/car/interior=chair
www.example.com/1/1/?l=thai 
www.example.com/1/1/?l=thai
www.example.com/1/1/?l=ukrainian
www.example.com/1/1/?l=turkish
www.example.com/1/1/?selectedTab=live&selectedStream=1
www.example.com/1/1/?l=ukrainian
www.example.com/1/1/?l=turkish
www.example.com/store/?l=turkish
www.example.com/1/1/storecommon.js?v=aHpFwmVHuavD&l=dutch
www.example.com/1/1/2/0/?l=english
www.example.com/1/1/9/0/?l=english
www.example.com/1/1/?l=spanish
```

There is one glitch with `?v=aHpFwmVHuavD&l=dutch`, which comprises of two parameters. They possibly ought to be broken down and processed one by one, which makes things more complex. **Make sure this is not the case.** Also note that `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` are **not** effectively the same.

Comment: Thanks, this nearly works however it doesnt delete some entries that it should

Comment: @jonnyb Can you give an example?

Comment: Here is some of the examples that remain: www.example.com/1/1/?l=thai
www.example.com/1/1/?l=thai
www.example.com/1/1/?l=ukrainian
www.example.com/1/1/?l=turkish
www.example.com/1/1/?selectedTab=live&selectedStream=1
www.example.com/1/1/?l=ukrainian
www.example.com/1/1/?l=turkish
www.example.com/store/?l=turkish
www.example.com/1/1/storecommon.js?v=aHpFwmVHuavD&l=dutch
www.example.com/1/1/2/0/?l=english
www.example.com/1/1/9/0/?l=english
www.example.com/1/1/?l=spanish

Comment: I think your script works as i asked, is my error in commuicating that some URL's have more then one folder eg. example.com/../../../../../ i will modify the question

Comment: @jonnyb Your list includes multiple parameters as in `www.example.com/1/1/storecommon.js?v=aHpFwmVHuavD&l=dutch`, so it's not going to be easy until you simplify their handling.

Comment: @jonnyb See my updated answer.

Comment: This is absolutely great. thanks very much for the help!